# changing class of li dynamically after hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I was wondering if there was anyway to dynamically change the class of a list when you hover over it.  Here is my code and fiddle.  When I hover over the li I want it to change the class. and on mouseout I want it to change back to original.

```
$('.navi > li').on("mouseover", function () {
    ($(this)).removeClass('.navi').addClass('.navi2');
    $('.hover-name', this).show();
}).on("mouseout", function() { 
    $('.hover-name').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Samfr/8/

Comment: you dont need the points by add or remove a class!

Comment: is there a reason you can't use `:hover` css selector ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had an extra period when adding and removing the class. Those should only be used to select the elements not change the class name.

```
$('.navi > li').on("mouseover", function () {
  ($(this)).removeClass('navi').addClass('navi2');
  $('.hover-name', this).show();
}).on("mouseout", function() { 
  $('.hover-name').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think hover might be a little better for what you are doing.
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Also, I'm not too clear on what you are asking but one of the examples on the above hover documentation page seems to describe something similar.

```
$( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );
  }
);
```

Comment: What about `$('td').hover(function(){$(this).toggleClass('hover')});`? :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

define a new class, for example dinamic-li

```
$('.dinamic-li').on("mouseenter", function () {
   $(this).addclass('navi');
   $(this).removeclass('navi2');
});

$('.dinamic-li').on("mouseleave", function () {
   $(this).addclass('navi2');
   $(this).removeclass('navi');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Will this work?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Samfr/10/)

Jquery:

```
$('.navi > li').on("mouseover", function () {
    $('.hover-name', this).show();
    $(this).attr('class', 'red');
}).on("mouseout", function() { 
    $('.hover-name').hide();
    $(this).attr('class', '');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

there is my solution:

```
$('.navi > li').on("mouseover", function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass(active);
    $('.hover-name', this).show();
}).on("mouseout", function() { 
    if( $(this).hasClass('active'))
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.hover-name').hide();
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Samfr/12/)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/Samfr/14/

This is that what u mean...

```
$('.navi > li').on("mouseover", function () {
    $(this).removeClass('navi').addClass('navi2');
    $('.hover-name', this).show();
}).on("mouseout", function() { 
    $('.hover-name').hide();
    $(this).removeClass('navi2').addClass('navi');
});
```

When you hover a link the color will be red and when you mouseout the color will reset.
That way you can see how the script works!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a CSS solution, it's much easier:

```
.hover-name { display: none; }
.navi li:hover .hover-name { display: block; }
```

Check your [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Samfr/17/)

Comment: I agree. Folks should stick with CSS first, and only move to Javascript if necessary.